# position: absolute displays cover each other

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to make a calendar in HTML. This is what I've done so far:
[image]

I use `position: absolute` to position the blue events, but the events cover each other. If two events are at same time, the two events' width should be half each.

```
<div class="event" [style.top]="calcTop(calendarEvent)"  [style.height]="calcHeight(calendarEvent)">
   <div> {{ calendarEvent.name }} </div>
</div>

.event {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: mat-color($app-primary, 600);
    text-align: center;
    border: #000 solid 1px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 20;
    clear: both;
```

Comment: Hi Balint, can you do two things for us? Confirm you mean width (and not height), and also share the generated/compiled HTML and CSS with us? Right now it looks like you have some pre-deployment code in the question, and we need to see the post-deployment code that the web browser would show a user.

Comment: There is no css-only way to do this. Find out on the server side if two events have the same time, and give those two events different classes (e.g. "event left" and "event right") so that you can target those with different CSS. Now how large is the chance that you can have three or more events at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need events at the same time to appear next to each other. Using flex you can easily achieve it. All you have to do is wrap the events div inside a container and apply some flex to it :P . Let's call the container as events-container. Here is the magic code

```
.events-container {
    display: flex;
}
.events {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/ajayvarghese/pen/qKWYaQ).